# How to set the state of a stepper in angular-material2?

Tags: angular-material2

I'm using the [Stepper component](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api) of angular-material2. How can I set the current state of a stepper? For example I want to set the current active step, or for any step set that it has to be disabled. I can see that there is a class [MatStepHeader](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepHeader) which seems to have what I need, but I couldn't figure out how to use it.